# How to create a dynamic property in this scenario

Tags: c#

I have a list which contains dynamic data. i.e

```
list[0].id=0;
list[1].id=1;
list[2].id=2;
```

I want to create a class which will have dynamic property names
i.e

```
for(int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
    //create dynamic class with dynamic property name
    new {id+i=list[i].id} //this statement throws compilation error. 
}
```

what is alternative to this method?

Comment: Which version of .net are you targeting?

Comment: do u really mean that this link solves my problem i am not finding anything like that

Comment: why do you want to have dynamic properties? consider reviewing your design

Comment: yes i want to set property name dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are after with Anonymous classes as they build at compile time and not runtime. You need to use the ExpandoObject class

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
var p = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;

for(int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
     p[id+i] = list[i].id;
}

//do something with the expando object
```

This is based on the post that Jani linked in his comment.